# Document Viewer is showing deleted files

Tags: pdf, document

Document Viewer is still showing deleted files from the directory, also from trash. What should I do to remove these deleted file icons / thumbnails?

[image: Screenshot - Document Viewer]

Comment: What if you delete them from trash? Do they still show up?

Comment: Can you right-click on the window to uncheck "Show hidden files" and check the issue again??

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi - Already deleted from the Trash, it is still showing.

Comment: @Ajay - I check to show hidden files, these files are not showing anywhere, except document viewer.

Comment: This seems to have been an issue 10 years ago, but was supposedly solved 5 years ago, as one can see in [this bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/369). I think that this is a new bug (not sure if there is a workaround) and it would be nice if you could report it [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues) so that the developers can take care of.